# Dynamic navigation links with Mysql, Php and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, dynamic, navigation

My Javascript function actually  works, but not on this code.

I get all the content displayed, **but the Navigation Links wont target my Iframe.**

Could anybody explain me what is wrong with my code?

Here is my code:

```
function goto(url) { 
           document.getElementById("contentFrame").contentWindow.location.replace(url);
           }
</script>

<title>SOLSTEN</title>
</head>    
<body>    
<div id="rubrik"><h1>SOLSTEN</h1></div>         
    <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'solsten');
            $sql = "select distinct productcategory from products";
            $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
                    echo "<div id='menu'>";
    while($myRow = $result->fetch_array())
                    {
                        echo "<ul>";
                        echo "<li style='display: inline;'><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='goto('imagegallery.php?category=".$myRow['productcategory']."')'> <h4>".$myRow["productcategory"]."</h4></a> </li>";
                        echo "</ul>";

                        } 
                    echo "</div>";  
    ?>

</div> 
     <div class='content'   >

<iframe src="imagegallery.php?category=Armband" scrolling="no" height='100%' width='100%' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' scrolling='auto' onload='' allowtransparency='false'   id="contentFrame"></iframe>"

</div>
```

I get a source code of my navigation links on this picture. >> http://test.mehmetakb.se/solsten1.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the src attribute of the iframe.

```
function goto(url) { 
           document.getElementById("contentFrame").src = url;
           }
```

**UPDATED**:

You have an error in your PHP code.
Change the A tag with this code:

```
onclick=\"goto('imagegallery.php?category=".$myRow['productcategory']."')\"
```

Take care of slashes.. If you have slashes into product category, you have to add some backslashes with addslashes PHP function, or a better way is to use PHP rawurlencode in order to encode in the URL format all characters..

Comment: The src="" of my Iframe is the default content of my iframe. But when I click on the navigation links, I get a source code like this. >> http://test.mehmetakb.se/solsten1.jpg